# How to keep track of sub-second time

Tags: c, linux

How can I keep track of time with sub second precision. Can you guys provide me with some ideas and strategies. Also, the pros and cons of each, I am trying to implement this for a hard real-time system using a Linux kernel. The Linux clock() function is not accurate enough since its precision is by seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655711/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-inside-linux-kernel

Comment: It really also depends of what time information you want. `clock` measures CPU time, `time` and `gettimeofday` measure wallclock time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) to return a `struct timespec`:

```
struct timespec {
        time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
        long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

The actual resolution is typically not anywhere near nanoseconds but should get you into the millisecond range or better.

Comment: +1, one big advantage of `clock_gettime` is also that you may chose the notion of time that you are interested in, CPU time or wallclock time.