# Subtraction of two unsigned long variables result in zero, even though each of their values are distinct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm writing a Linux Kernel Module to calculate the function's running time in jiffies.

```
static int thread_fn(void *unused) {
      unsigned long j_0, j_1, j_seconds;
      int a, b, sum;
      printk("Inside thread creation's function\n");  
      j_0 = jiffies;
      a = 100;
      b = 200;
      sum = a+b;
      printk("Result of addition is %ld\n",sum);
      j_1 = jiffies;
      j_seconds = j_1 - j_0;
      printk("Time elapsed in jiffies: %lu\n", j_seconds);
      while(!kthread_should_stop())
        schedule();
      return 0;
    }
```

I'm assigning `j_0` an initial jiffy counter value, and `j_1` the extended jiffy value. When I subtract them both, they give me 0, even though `j_0` and `j_1` are distinct values.

---

Edit 1: I'm sorry. I printed both `j_0` and `j_1` during the same execution and they're not distinct. I printed `j_0` and `j_1` separately during different module insertions, hence the reason to why I thought they were distinct.

So, my question now is, why isn't jiffies incrementing? Shouldn't they since operations occur between the two calls?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: *"even though `j_0` and `j_1` are distinct values."* Are you sure? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: How do you know j_0 and j_1 are different? They will normally be the same as not enough time elapses for jiffies to change in most cases. Why not print them out when you print out j_seconds?

Comment: if j_0-j_1==0, so j_0==j_1, because unsigned followes modular arithmetic.

Comment: Apologies, I have made the edit.

Comment: If another thread accesses (sets) `jeffies` concurrently to the thread function you show access to this shared resource (`jiffies`) shall be protected, else undefined behaviour might occur. Such kind of protection typically is done using a common mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `j_1 == j_0`. This is understandable as `jiffies` is incremented every timer interrupt. The frequency with which this happens can be defined by `CONFIG_HZ`, e.g. on my VM:

```
grep 'CONFIG_HZ=' /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_HZ=250
```

250Hz = one timer interrupt every 4 ms. This granularity is way too coarse to measure the impact of a printk (and a single addition).

For sub-jiffy time measurements, you can use `ftrace`, `do_gettimeofday` or `perf`. This has been asked before. See e.g. [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655711/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-inside-linux-kernel/4656090).